# Animation-list on Menu Item Icon

Tags: android, animation, menuitem

I want to have an Menu item in the ActionBar that visualizes a boolean value. If this boolean value is true, the icon should start animating a series of 2 images in a loop. I did the following:

I added an item in the menu.xml file:

```
  <item
     android:id='@+id/myAnimation'
     android:icon='@drawable/pic1'
     android:showAsAction='ifRoom'>
  </item>
```

I created an animation-list:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<animation-list xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    android:oneshot='false' >
    <item
        android:drawable='drawable/pic1'
        android:duration='100' />
    <item
      android:drawable='drawable/pic2'
      android:duration='100' />
</animation-list>
```

In the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` I assign this menu item to a variable

```
myMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.myAnimation);
```

Now, I was hoping to add an animation which would get executed whenever I tell the menu item to animate. But I wasn't able to come even close.

- is this even possible?
- How can I do that?

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
The App should support API from 8

Answer (score 2):

I did `((AnimationDrawable) item.getIcon()).start();` in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`
This did not work. Then I thought, maybe it should be done on the UI thread, and then this worked:

```
someView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((AnimationDrawable) item.getIcon()).start();
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and just found your question unanswered, so here is the solution, from the [Android dev website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html):

```
((AnimationDrawable)myMenuItem).start();
```

Comment: you probably mean ((AnimationDrawable)myMenuItem.getIcon()).start().  MenuItem is not a AnimationDrawable and cannot be cast to one.